# How to compile C into a universal library that works with iOS architectures

Tags: ios, c, xcode, static-libraries, cross-compiling

I'm trying to compile a very small amount of C source into a library that I can use in XCode for an iOS application.

The files are a single `.c` file and three header files. I'm very new to C, and no matter what I try I can't seem to get them to compile into a library that supports iOS architectures.

The files depend on the openssl library, and I've got that installed and working fine.

I just need to know the process of compiling these four files into a single library. I've found a plethora of information on the subject online, but I can't decipher which parts are necessary for what I'm trying to do.

I've tried the following:

```
gcc -fPIC -c main.c
gcc -shared -o mylib.so main.o -lcrypto -lssl
```

which seems to compile it for x86_64, (I've not tested the resulting file, just checked it's arch).

I've also tried

```
./configure --disable-shared --enable-utf8 --host=arm-apple-darwin CFLAGS="-arch armv7 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.1.sdk" CXXFLAGS="-arch armv7 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.1.sdk" LDFLAGS="-L." CC="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/cc" CXX="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/c++"
```

which only gives me errors

```
checking for arm-apple-darwin-gcc... no
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/Users/nathanf/compilec':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
```

I've been scouring the internet for the last few days trying to figure this out, but it's so convoluted to cross compile just a few files and I'm frustrated so I came here for some input.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I haven't done this, but I would think you would need to be working on a Mac. Then the simplest thing would be to created an Xcode project which builds an iOS framework.

Comment: @drekka I am compiling on a mac, and when I try to create the library in xcode and link openssl library to it i get `-lssl is not an object file (not allowed in a library)`